# How can I ignore a specific part of code the first time a loop is ran?

Tags: c++, function, io

I'm writing a project for articles in store and I need help with the following :

I have declared a struct with elements:

```
struct pole{
    int sifra;              // code
    string opis;            // description
    float cena;             // price
    int vlez_kol;           // qty
    int izlez_kol;          // qty
    float dan_stapka;       // 
    float iznos;            // 
    int datum;              // date
};
```

And my program's code has this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < br_artikli; i++){
    cout << "Enter the description of the product" << endl;
    vlez_artikl(artikli[i]);
}
```

And my function is the following :

```
void vlez_artikl(pole &artikli){
    do{
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, artikli.opis);
    }while(golemina_string(artikli.opis) >= 30);
}
```

And `golemina_string` function is to check length of string:

```
int golemina_string(string text){
    return text.length();
}
```

So, I was wondering, how can I make the program output an ERROR when the user enters a string >= 30 length, and to not show it before he makes an error. I tried several ways, but couldn't manage it. So, I thought of maybe adding

```
cout << "Error" << endl;
```

In the beginning of the function for inputting data, and somehow ignore (not display the text) the first time when the program enters the function, but I haven't found any way to do that, any help is appreciated.

Example:
`Enter the description of the product`

When user inputs: `wewrfoeshfoisfhoiasohidasfdhioadfsoihadsfhioafhiodsafoihdsoaihdsf`

To output `error` and let him choose a new number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
void vlez_artikl(pole &artikli){
    for(;;) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, artikli.opis);
        if (golemina_string(artikli.opis) >= 30)
           cout << "String too long, try again" << endl;
        else break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just do a while(true) loop?

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: It's a bit easier to read in my opinion.  Guess that's just my personal preference though.

Comment: Yes, a competent C or C++ programmer should be well familiar with `for(;;)` idiom.

Comment: @piokuc Why? The only advantage is slightly shorter code (and not necessarily faster to type, since there are more symbols). Source code bytes aren't that expensive. I don't see a practical use for it, and thus I don't see why experienced programmers would necessarily be familiar with it.

Comment: Because all the classic books on C use this idiom and there is plenty of code out there which uses this idiom. That's why a competent C programmer shouldn't have difficulties in understanding it. Of course, you are free to use `while(true)` instead, if you prefer, there is nothing wrong with it either.